# What is the average number of moves it takes to solve every 3x3 rubik’s cube position if only random moves are made?

Tags: probability, average, rubiks-cube

Hope my question is clear enough. I’m just curious.

Comment: If you're still here Hunter, please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and edit your question.

Comment: it is not clear because it depends on the general strategy/random criteria you want to use

Comment: if you make a move randomly chosen then you can in theory never finish the cube, while if you use an algorithm made to solve the cube it should have an upper bound of moves